# Rewrite "matching algorithm" in Java 8 style

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, refactoring, java-stream

I have one "matching algorithm" method that wrote using loops and if conditions.
If it possible (and if it needed) to rewrite this code in Java 8 style?

```
private boolean matchIdsAndStatuses(List<Item> items, ItemResponse currentItemResponse, StatusValue statusValue) {
     boolean isMatched = false;
     if (CollectionUtils.isNonEmpty(items)) {

         // Set of currentItemResponse ids
         Set<Map.Entry<String, Status>> itemIds = currentItemResponse.getMapIdsAndStatuses().entrySet();

         // List of inner items ids
         List<String> innerItemIds =
             items.stream().map(ItemBase::getInnerId).collect(Collectors.toList());

         // Do we rewrite following block of code in Java 8 style?
         // Iterate through inner items ids
         for (String innerItemId: innerItemIds) {

             // Iterate through currentItemResponse ids
             for (Map.Entry<String, Status> itemId: itemIds) {

                 // Check if innerItemIds and statuses were matched
                 if (Objects.equals(innerItemId, itemId.getKey())
                     && itemId.getValue().getStatusValue().equals(status)) {
                     isMatched = true;
                     break;
                 } else {
                     isMatched = false;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return isMatched;
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you doing `Objects.equals(innerItemId, itemId.getKey())` instead of `currentItemResponse.getMapIdsAndStatuses().get(innerItemId)`?

Comment: That's interesting point, I'll try to follow your advice, thanks!

Comment: Why does `Status` have a method `getStatus()`?

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in your logic. `break;` only breaks from the inner loop; the outer loop will continue to execute, possibly overwriting the previous results. If you mean to check if *any* match, you should return true as soon as a match is found. If you mean to check if *all* match, you should return false as soon as the inner loop completes with `isMatched` still false. It would help greatly if you explained what you're trying to do in plain English so we don't have to guess.

Comment: @shmosel, it's just a draft copy of real code.

Comment: That's doesnt help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @shmosel, I want to check if all elements from outer loop matches with elements from inner loop, so all good with business logic here, I'm sorry for incomplete explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, what about the `getStatus()` method? Is that really necessary?

Comment: @shmosel, yes, actually it's necessary :(

Comment: So `Status.getStatus()` returns another `Status` different from itself?

Comment: @shmosel, let me introduce you in Status logic: Status status as parameter of this method actully is StatusValue type. But currentItemResponse variable has map as field (getMapIdsAndStatuses) with String as key and StatusBasic as value. StatusBasic has two field with types: StatusValue and StatusExternalValue. So why this code seems a little bit tangled.

Comment: I see. Let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check that each of `items` is mapped to the given `status` in `currentItemResponse.getMapIdsAndStatuses()`. I *think* this will do what you want:

```
private boolean matchIdsAndStatuses(List<Item> items, ItemResponse currentItemResponse, StatusValue statusValue) {
    return items.stream()
            .map(ItemBase::getInnerId)
            .map(currentItemResponse.getMapIdsAndStatuses()::get)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(Status::getStatusValue)
            .filter(statusValue::equals)
            .count() == items.size();
}
```

On second thought, I would recommend using instead the [short-circuiting `allMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) operation. This will stop iterating as soon as a non-match is found:

```
return items.stream()
        .map(ItemBase::getInnerId)
        .map(currentItemResponse.getMapIdsAndStatuses()::get)
        .allMatch(s -> s != null && s.getStatusValue().equals(status));
```

Comment: That interesting. Let me ask you what this code block do: we get stream of items then map to innerId. Then we get entry from mapIdsAndStatuses by previously mapped innerId (get by key) and filtered if this items exists in map. Then map StatusValue from this map and filter with supplied status in method parameter. And if amount items equals items that matching the condition we return true, am I right?

Comment: Perfect, it's works also for cases when we have 2 items and only 1 record in map from currentItemResponse, so the issue is solved. You save my day and give me another view on functional programming, thank you very much!

Comment: @goodCoder No problem. Please see my update for a possible improvement.

Answer (score 0):

It is required to iterate through items and check if their ID matches the ItemResponse. In addition the item status has to be checked against the parameter. In order to simplify things the example uses different types, but the end result might look similar to the following:

```
private boolean matchIdsAndStatuses(List<String> items, Map<String, String> currentItemResponse, String status) {
    return items.stream()
            .map(innerItemId -> innerItemId)
            .anyMatch(innerItemId -> currentItemResponse.keySet().contains(innerItemId)
                    && currentItemResponse.get(innerItemId).contains(status));
}
```

First we extract the innerItemId, then we check if thats a valid key and finally we fetch the status by key and compare it with the parameter.